# Does using many @Output in angular component have any performance issue?

Tags: angular

Does having many **@Output()** in angular component leads to a performance penalty ?

note - angular uses  RxJS Subject to create the functionality - https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#transmitting-data-between-components

Comment: could estimate `many` ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. Though you may have resource leaks if you're subscribing to the observable streams and not unsubscribing on `ngOnDestroy` and this could negatively impact your performance eventually.